# On the characterization of the least singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, svd, singular-values

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ real or complex matrix. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76986/522332) it is shown that

$$\sigma_{min}(A)=\min_{x\in F^n, \|x\|=1}\|Ax\| \quad \quad (1)$$

where $\sigma_{min}(A)$ denotes the "least" singular value of $A$.

Usually this means $\sigma_{min}(A):=\sigma_{q}(A)$ with $q=\min\{m,n\}$. But then consider the case $n>m$:

Then $\text{rank(A)}\leq m<n$ so there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$, and WLOG we may assume $\|x\|=1$. Hence the right-hand side of $(1)$ is zero. But if $\text{rank(A)}= m$, then the left-hand side of $(1)$ is strictly positive.

Am I missing something? Do we need to define $\sigma_{min}(A):=\sigma_{n}(A)$ for the above to work?

Comment: No, you are not missing something. The statement as posed is simply wrong. It should be $\sigma_{\min}(A) = \min \{\|Ax\| \mid \|x\|=1 \wedge x\in \ker(A)^\perp \}$

Comment: @Hyperplane I see, but we still have $\sigma_{n}(A)=\min_{x\in F^n, \|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$ right? (With the definition $\sigma_{n}(A)=0$ if $n>m$).